# Додать проперти к модели, которие не будут использоватся EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Доброго дня.
У меня такой вопрос.
Есть таблица в бд з столбцами  UserID,UserName,Password
,и клас модели с такими же пропертями.В некоторих случаях, скажем,
при изменении пароля мне надо додать к модели еще newPassword,ConfirmPassword но сделать
чтоб newPassword,ConfirmPassword проперти не мапались на столбци в таблице бд, то есть чтоб не их не использовал EntityFramework.
Если их просто додать к модели, то при context.SaveChanges() виваливается ексепшнн..
Я использую MVC3 и EF4.
спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно в OnModelCreating указать, какие поля не добавлять в базу

```
public class Context : DbContext
{       
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      modelBuilder.Entity<TYPE>().Ignore(c => c.PROPERTY);
   }
}
```

Можно пометить атрибутом в модели

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerID { set; get; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int Age { set; get; }
}
```